# Having trouble with GLFW library linking using a makefile

Tags: c++, opengl, makefile, glfw

I've been working on learning OpenGL on a windows machine running MinGW and I been able to compile and run an OpenGL program using the standard  includes and glu32.dll and etc.  This time I'm trying to compile a basic shader which seemed to be simple enough if I used GLFW, GLAD, GLM, and their respective dependencies.  I think I have everything other than GLFW properly included.

*My Makefile:*

```
all:
    g++ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -g -c deps/glad/*.c
    g++ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -g -c src/common/*.cpp
    g++ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -g -c src/objects/*.cpp
    g++ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -g -c src/objects/mesh/*.cpp
    g++ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -g -c src/*.cpp
    g++ -Wall -g *.o -o run$(EXEEXT) -L ./ -lgdi32 -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lglfw3
    make clean

clean:
    cmd.exe /c del *.o
```

*Running this* however gives linking errors for functions from GLFW

```
C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app>make
    g++ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -g -c deps/glad/*.c
    g++ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -g -c src/common/*.cpp
    g++ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -g -c src/objects/*.cpp
    g++ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -g -c src/objects/mesh/*.cpp
    g++ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -g -c src/*.cpp
    In file included from c:\users\plore\desktop\app\deps\glm\detail/func_exponential_simd.inl:4:0,
                     from c:\users\plore\desktop\app\deps\glm\detail/func_exponential.inl:150,
                     from c:\users\plore\desktop\app\deps\glm\exponential.hpp:110,
                     from c:\users\plore\desktop\app\deps\glm\detail/func_geometric.inl:1,
                     from c:\users\plore\desktop\app\deps\glm\geometric.hpp:116,
                     from c:\users\plore\desktop\app\deps\glm\detail/func_matrix.inl:1,
                     from c:\users\plore\desktop\app\deps\glm\matrix.hpp:161,
                     from src/shader/../../deps/glm/./ext/../detail/type_mat2x2.inl:1,
                     from src/shader/../../deps/glm/./ext/../detail/type_mat2x2.hpp:176,
                     from src/shader/../../deps/glm/./ext/matrix_double2x2.hpp:5,
                     from src/shader/../../deps/glm/mat2x2.hpp:5,
                     from src/shader/../../deps/glm/glm.hpp:119,
                     from src/shader/shader_s.h:15,
                     from src/main.cpp:20:
    c:\users\plore\desktop\app\deps\glm\simd\exponential.h: In function 'glm_f32vec4 glm_vec1_sqrt_lowp(glm_f32vec4)':
    c:\users\plore\desktop\app\deps\glm\simd\exponential.h:10:64: warning: SSE vector return without SSE enabled changes the ABI [-Wpsabi]
     GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER glm_f32vec4 glm_vec1_sqrt_lowp(glm_f32vec4 x)
                                                                    ^
    g++ -Wall -g *.o -o run -L ./ -lgdi32 -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lglfw3
    Warning: resolving ___glutInitWithExit@12 by linking to ___glutInitWithExit
    Use --enable-stdcall-fixup to disable these warnings
    Use --disable-stdcall-fixup to disable these fixups
    Warning: resolving ___glutCreateWindowWithExit@8 by linking to ___glutCreateWindowWithExit
    Warning: resolving ___glutCreateMenuWithExit@8 by linking to ___glutCreateMenuWithExit
    Warning: resolving _glPushMatrix@0 by linking to _glPushMatrix
    Warning: resolving _glTranslatef@12 by linking to _glTranslatef
    Warning: resolving _glRotatef@16 by linking to _glRotatef
    Warning: resolving _glPopMatrix@0 by linking to _glPopMatrix
    Warning: resolving _glColor3f@12 by linking to _glColor3f
    Warning: resolving _glBegin@4 by linking to _glBegin
    Warning: resolving _glVertex2f@8 by linking to _glVertex2f
    Warning: resolving _glEnd@0 by linking to _glEnd
    main.o: In function `Z12processInputP10GLFWwindow':
    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/src/main.cpp:35: undefined reference to `_imp__glfwGetKey'
    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/src/main.cpp:36: undefined reference to `_imp__glfwSetWindowShouldClose'
    main.o: In function `main':
    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/src/main.cpp:121: undefined reference to `_imp__glfwInit'
    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/src/main.cpp:122: undefined reference to `_imp__glfwWindowHint'
    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/src/main.cpp:123: undefined reference to `_imp__glfwWindowHint'
    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/src/main.cpp:124: undefined reference to `_imp__glfwWindowHint'
    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/src/main.cpp:132: undefined reference to `_imp__glfwCreateWindow'
    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/src/main.cpp:136: undefined reference to `_imp__glfwTerminate'
    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/src/main.cpp:139: undefined reference to `_imp__glfwMakeContextCurrent'
    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/src/main.cpp:140: undefined reference to `_imp__glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback'
    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/src/main.cpp:144: undefined reference to `_imp__glfwGetProcAddress'
    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/src/main.cpp:255: undefined reference to `_imp__glfwWindowShouldClose'
    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/src/main.cpp:279: undefined reference to `_imp__glfwSwapBuffers'
    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/src/main.cpp:280: undefined reference to `_imp__glfwPollEvents'
    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/src/main.cpp:291: undefined reference to `_imp__glfwTerminate'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 1

    C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app>
```

From reading about other people issues on this matter it seems to be a problem with the compiler not finding libglfw3.a and libglfw3dll.a which i placed in the same directory as all the other dlls.

This is the *contents of my directory*, with src having my main.cpp and deps having the headers for the includes.

```
C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9CEF-2A78

 Directory of C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app

11/29/2018  07:46 PM    <DIR>          .
11/29/2018  07:46 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/29/2018  07:39 PM    <DIR>          deps
08/18/2016  06:04 AM           238,974 glfw3.dll
11/27/2018  04:26 PM           245,760 glu32.dll
11/27/2018  04:26 PM           237,568 glut32.dll
08/18/2016  06:05 AM           150,452 libglfw3.a
08/18/2016  06:05 AM            65,788 libglfw3dll.a
11/29/2018  07:43 PM               515 Makefile
11/27/2018  04:26 PM           757,248 opengl32.dll
11/27/2018  04:26 PM                55 README.md
11/29/2018  12:10 PM    <DIR>          src
               8 File(s)      1,696,360 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  27,734,446,080 bytes free

C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

**Update:**
I have tried different orders with linked libraries but they have not had any effect.  However, interestingly enough removing `libglfw3.a` and `libglfw3dll.a` allows the program to compile only to then crash instantly.  Debugging with gdb yields the following

```
C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app>gdb
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
(gdb) file run.exe
Reading symbols from C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app\run.exe...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app/run.exe
[New Thread 13120.0x3c3c]
[New Thread 13120.0x38a8]
[New Thread 13120.0x2b08]
[New Thread 13120.0x37bc]
[New Thread 13120.0x828]
[New Thread 13120.0x2810]
[New Thread 13120.0x39d0]
[New Thread 13120.0x3c34]
[New Thread 13120.0x1610]
[New Thread 13120.0x268c]
[New Thread 13120.0x3600]
[New Thread 13120.0x319c]
[New Thread 13120.0x34d8]
[New Thread 13120.0x15ec]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x692b1d25 in _glfwRefreshContextAttribs () from C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app\glfw3.dll
(gdb) where
#0  0x692b1d25 in _glfwRefreshContextAttribs () from C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app\glfw3.dll
#1  0x63f1f3ff in wglSwapLayerBuffers () from C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app\opengl32.dll
#2  0x00003c3c in ?? ()
#3  0x63f1f632 in wglSwapLayerBuffers () from C:\Users\plore\Desktop\app\opengl32.dll
#4  0x36384224 in ?? ()
#5  0x0068fcf8 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb)
```

Comment: `libglfw3.a` and `libglfw3dll.a` are not dlls and if linker didn't  find them then it would issue corresponding error. Most likely the problem is the order of libraries and use of `-L` instead of `-l` for `glfw3`.

Comment: Oh wow, that was stupid of me to use -L instead of -l.  I've moved around the library order some but have had no success.  Fixing that typo didn't actually change anything either sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was simple.  I discovered that I could open libglfw3dll.a as an archive and saw it was filled with #####.o files which defined the glfw functions.  Extracting this and placing it with makefile to let it complile them alongside my .o files removed this error but had strange linking issues when executed.

The answer was to link libglfw3dll.a alongside the .o files as if it were a source. meaning my makefile became

```
all:
    g++ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -g -c deps/glad/*.c
    g++ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -g -c src/common/*.cpp
    g++ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -g -c src/objects/*.cpp
    g++ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -g -c src/objects/mesh/*.cpp
    g++ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -g -c src/*.cpp
    g++ -Wall -g *.o *.a -o run$(EXEEXT) -L ./ -lgdi32 -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lglfw3
    make clean

clean:
    cmd.exe /c del *.o
```

This compiled and executed fine although now I'm running into an issue getting `glfwCreateWindow()` working but that is probably a separate issue

Best of luck to anyone else who runs into this!